# Espaçamento entre divs sobrepõe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

Eu tenho [esse site](http://righetti.com.br/th-new/) que contém um *slider* o problema que está acontecendo é que dependendo do tamanho da tela o espaçamento entre cada slide muda, alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver isto?

Estou usando o plugin `bxslider`. O certo era ter um espaçamento de 14px, mesmo definindo e tudo, dependendo da resolução muda, por exemplo, na resolução `1920x1080` fica certo, mas se mudar de resolução dá problema.

Como proceder?

Comment: Você deveria especificar melhor de qual "espaçamento" estás falando, porém eu deduzi duas coisas que poderiam estar dando problema, caso eu esteja errado, edite sua questão informando o espaçamento desejado

Answer (score 1):

Crie seu slide responsivo, é bem mais simples e evita muita dor de cabeça.

```
/* Desktop maiores */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* tables em formato porta retrato até os desktos no formato paisagem */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* dispositivo em paisagem até os tablets em formato porta-retrato */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* dispositivo no formato paisagem e abaixos */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Assim você consegue atingir um publico bem maior e resolver seu problema, caso você não entenda no lugar dos ... você coloca seu css usando o max-width como base na resolução.

Comment: Embora essa não seja a solução do problema, mas uma boa recomendação, seria melhor ainda se ela fosse "mobile first", mais ou menos isso: faça o site como se fosse para um celular, adapte-o para funcionar em telas maiores. Do exemplo, tente tirar todos os `max-width` (mais informações: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/).

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o espaçamento que estejas falando é a propriedade `padding` do CSS, por isso com este codigo CSS, você terá o espaçamento correto, porém o correto seria aprender a fazer a alteração direto no seu plugin, você deveria procurar a documentação do tal `bxslider` e ler para aprender a usa-lo corretamente.

**Caso não seja esta propriedade, que resolva seu problema, por favor, explique mais detalhadamente de qual "espaçamento" estás falando.**

Porém estou deduzindo que seja um dos dois códigos abaixo que resolvam seu problema:

```css
.slide_txt {
    padding-left: 14px !important;
}
```

Ou seria este aqui:

```css
.bxslider li {
  margin-right: 14px !important;
}
```

**O seletor `!important` faz com que todas as outras definições do mesmo elemento e mesma propriedade sejam ignoradas e torna esta a mais importante.**

Comment: Seria sobre o slide_txt? seria o espaçamento tipo entre a li, o slide_txt seria a parte de texto dentro. Então, o bxslider tem uma propriedade para isso
slideMargin Margin between each slide
Mas dá o mesmo problema

Comment: então o correto seria este segundo código que postei na minha ultima edição veja

Comment: mesmo assim parece que não dá, estranho que o plugin muda o tamanho da li, acho que este é o ponto que está dando problema, vou tentar achar a parte que muda para corrigir

Comment: Mas não há como o plugin ou nada mudar uma propriedade CSS aplicada a um elemento tão diretamente utilizando um `!important` por isso esta `margin-right` que te forneci sempre irá funcionar, porém pode estar acontecendo de em alguns casos o plugin estar utilizando `margin-left`, você tem como me mostrar melhor qual problema estás passando?

Comment: Style da LI em 1280 float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 668.5px; margin-right: 14px;
em 1440 float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 666.5px; margin-right: 14px;
No caso alguma coisa do plugin está alterando o tamanho de cada slide, dependendo do tamanho da tela pode chegar a 500px, acho que muda depois que atualiza a página

Comment: Bom, isto é uma ação natural do slider, afinal quanto menor a resolução menor será a sua visualização, porém, você pode aplicar um tamanho padrão para todas as resoluções ou um valor ajustável que seria em `%` qual seria melhor para você?

Comment: Bem, comentei a linha 224 do slider [slider.children.css('width', getSlideWidth());] e deu certo, estou meio com a entrega apertada, mas dai qualquer coisa uso media-queries para ajustar em resoluções menores que 912px. Valeu pela ajuda cara

Comment: Ok, grato em ajudar, se quiseres uma solução melhor, só avisar.

Comment: Seria legal, tentei seguir a documentação especificando o tamanho do slide (slideWidth ) e a margem (slideMargin), mas dava diferença.
O problema que peguei agora testando aqui é o Internet Explorer 9, mas dai já deve ser outra coisa que está dando essa diferença

Comment: tente usar uma `<div>` que englobe todos os slides que tenha definido no css o tamanho, e suas `<li>`'s que são os slides, você pode dividir em `3` ou `2`, pra `3` seria: `width: 33.333%` e `height: 100%;` cada, e pra `2` seria: `width: 50%` e `height: 100%` cada.